# checkbox с передачей значения

Tags: typescript, angular

как написать чекбокс так что бы при выборе " Х or O " то что пользыватель нажмет передавалось по клику мышки в ячейку с игрой?

вот html

```
<p>Make a choice</p>
<select class="playerSelect">
<option>X</option>
<option>O</option>
</select>
```

component.ts

```
   export class GamePageComponent implements OnInit {


  reload (){
    window.location.reload()
  }
  newArr: boolean [] = [false, false,false, false,false, false,false, false,false];
  
  onClick(index: number) : void {
    /*alert('Button ' + index + ' clicked')*/
    
  this.newArr[index] = true;

    console.log(index);
  }


  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  }
```

мне нужно что бы после выбора пользывателя еслион выберит "О" то первый ход будет "О" если он выберит "Х" то первый ход будет "Х". Как передать данные который выберит пользыватель через мой чекбокс?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого надо повесить обработчик на checkbox

```
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    console.log("Checkbox is checked..");
  } else {
    console.log("Checkbox is not checked..");
  }
});
```

Comment: а как передать тогда инпут в клетку после выбора?

Comment: Для этого нужно более детально расписать вопрос и добавить код

Comment: Да минутку  исправлю пост